# Drop down menu shortcut for left margin Resharper helper icon like inline Ctrl+.?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper-6.0

Being able to use Ctrl+. and Enter save me alot of time. I would like to be able to do this with the Resharper Icon that shows in the left margin. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default shortcut key for it is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.